# Forwarding to external resource using an Ingress controller

Tags: gcloud

I have been using the GCLB Ingress Controller to forward outside traffic to my in-cluster services, and this has been working great so far.

But, is there a way that based on a route/path match, traffic could be forwarded to outside of cluster resource. From the documentation, I can't seem to find anything and I don't think it can be achieved using GCLB Ingress Controller; but I haven't yet tried the NGINX Ingress Controller.

Is this a behavior that can be achieved using any of these 2 controllers? I would prefer using the native gcloud one, the GCLB but the other one works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can help you [kubernates external service](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/externalname-services)